# Рефакторинг кода простой игры

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, code-style, инспекция-кода

В чем архитектурные недостатки данного кода и как можно их исправить?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String ars[]){
        int l = 0;
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Выберите всадника апокалипсиса");
        System.out.println("1 - желтый");
        System.out.println("2 - черный");
        System.out.println("3 - красный");
        System.out.println("4 - оранжевый");
        System.out.println("5 - синий");

        int j = scn.nextInt();
        switch(j){
        case 1:
            j = 1;
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали первого всадника");
            break;
        case 2:
            j = 2;
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали второгое всадника");
            break;
        case 3:
            j = 3;
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали третьего всадника");
            break;
        case 4:
            j = 4;
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали четвертого всадника");
            break;
        case 5:
            j = 5;
            System.out.println("Вы выбрали пятого всадника");
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Выберите всадников из списка!!");
        }
        int a = (int)(Math.random()*4+1);
            if (a == 1){
            System.out.println("Сегодня - Победил жёлтый всадник");
        }else if(a == 2){
            System.out.println("Сегодня - Победил черный всадник");
        }else if(a == 3){
            System.out.println("Сегодня - Победил красный всадник");
        }else if(a == 4){
            System.out.println("Сегодня - Победил оранжевый всадник");
        }else if(a == 5){
            System.out.println("Сегодня - Победил синий всадник");
        }   
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(j);

            if (a==j){
            System.out.println("Вы победили, вы молодец!");
            }else
                System.out.println("Вы проиграли. Ничего страшного, бывает");
    }
}
```

---

Comment: убери j = 2; вот эти присвоения

Comment: Поясните, в чем возникла проблема? Напишите информативный заголовок. В текущей формулировке этот вопрос будет удален

Comment: да, не очень понятно, что должно быть и в чем проблема, только в "чистоте" кода?

Comment: @DenisZinkovskiy, думаю да, тут речь о чистоте кода. А закрывать не надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, свое мнение против закрытия

Comment: @tutankhamun, вроде очевидно, что вопросы по качеству кода не являются оффтопиком. На английском SO даже метка для этого есть - code-quality (в добавок к coding-style, design-patterns и anti-patterns).

Comment: @Qwertiy Это очевидно, согласен. Но! У вопроса нет нормального заголовка и поясняющий текст не очень поясняет в чем именно возникла проблема у автора. Я вижу что с качеством кода беда, но вот это-ли та проблема, с которой сюда пришел автор? На телепатию надежды мало

Comment: Кстати я не голосовал за закрытие... пока

Comment: Ну вот, вопрос еще и минус подхватил. @Dea, внесите, пожалуйста, ясность в текст вопроса

Comment: Автор, я вам немного подправил заголовок и текст.

Answer (score 1):

Код плохо обозрим, это да.

Я бы сделал так: поместил бы все сообщения, относящиеся к конкретному всаднику, в отдельную структуру данных. И обращался бы через неё.

Тогда код бы выглядел как-то так:

```
System.out.println("Выберите всадника апокалипсиса");
for (Knight k : knights)
    System.out.println(k.Texts.Prompt);

Knight chosenKnight = null;
while (chosenKnight == null)
{
    int j = scn.nextInt();
    if (j < 1 || j > knights.size())
    {
        System.out.println("Выберите всадников из списка!!");
        continue;
    }
    chosenKnight = knights[j - 1];
}

System.out.println(chosenKnight.Texts.ChoiceConfirmation);

int a = (int)(Math.random() * knights.size());
Knight winningKnight = knights[a];
System.out.println(winningKnight.Texts.WinnerAnnouncement);

if (chosenKnight == winningKnight)
    System.out.println("Вы победили крч, красавец чувак!!");
else
    System.out.println("Вы просрали свои деньги крч");
```

(Впрочем, остальные тексты я бы тоже куда-то выгрузил.)

Comment: `System.out.println("Пацан к успеху шел, не получилось, не фартануло.");`

Comment: Там ведь `j` имелась в виду?

Comment: Всадников апокалипсиса четыре штуки, а не 5. Чума, Война, Голод и Смерть. Миф возникший из суровых реалий средневековой Европы.

Comment: @igumnov: Точно! Подправил код, чтобы он был совместим с [этим](http://ocad.thecreativesolution.ca/plog-content/images/art-of-europethe-northern-renaissance/mathias-grunewald---lucas-cranach/0045-1.jpg).